# Applying newcommand/def to subscript whenever one is provided

Tags: macros, def

I have defined a `\blue` command which I often use with subscripts, e.g.

```
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{{\color{blue} \textup{\textbf{#1}}}}
\blue{v}_{\blue{ij}}
```

**Question:** Is there a way to define `\blue` in such a way that I can *simply* write

```
\blue{v}_{ij}
```

to get the same result as for `\blue{v}_{\blue{ij}}`, without changing the behavior of `\blue{v}`?

Comment: why do use use `\text...` comands (so the text fonts not the math fonts) here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I don't really like this kind of construct which hides its behaviour under an apparently easier syntax, but here you go:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\NewDocumentCommand{\blue}{me{_}}{\mathcolor{blue}{\mathbf{#1}\IfValueT{#2}{_{\mathbf{#2}}}}}

\begin{document}
See $\blue{v}$ or $\blue{v}_{ij}$, but $\blue{v}^a$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not `\mathcolor`?

Comment: @egreg Because I keep forgetting that it's in the kernel now... `:-)`